# How to speed up start time in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am starting to write a game but whenever I run my code it takes 2 minutes to boot up and even then some methods are not working. The main ones that's not working are quitting pygame and drawGameScene().

**My code is:**

```py
import  os, random
from pygame import *

init()

os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d, %d" %(0, 20)

scalefactor = 2

FPS = 60

screenWidth = round(224 * scalefactor)
screenHeight = round(298 * scalefactor)

size = screenWidth, screenHeight

screen = display.set_mode(size)

button = 0

RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)

STATEGAME = 1
STATEQUIT = 3

curState = STATEGAME

titleFont = font.SysFont("Times New Roman",45)

def drawText(words, screen,position, color, font):
    text = font.render(words, False, color)
    textSize = text.get_size()

    position[0] = position[0] - textSize[0]//2
    position[1] = position[1] - textSize[1]//2

    #centers the text
    screen.blit(text,position)

def gameRun():
    while curState != STATEQUIT:
        if curState == STATEGAME:
            drawGameScene()
            eventCheck()
            updater()

def eventCheck():
    for evnt in event.get():
        if evnt.type == QUIT:
            curState == STATEQUIT

def updater():
    pass

def drawGameScene():
    draw.rect(screen,RED,(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight))
    drawText("High Score", screen, [0,0], BLUE, titleFont)
    display.update

gameRun()

display.flip()
```

**no error messages are given**
**Please Help, It's for a project**

Comment: You should add some logging to find the line that consumes the time.

Answer (score 0):

For the quitting pygame:

You should use the code as below:

```
for events in event.get():

    if events.type == QUIT:

        pygame.quit()
        exit() #this is from sys module
```

This way, your pygame is quitted at the first place. So, you don't need anything about curstate, etc.

Also, you need to use while True statement to repeat the blitting process.

Full code:

```
import os, random
from pygame import *
from sys import exit
init()
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d, %d" %(0, 20)
scalefactor = 2
FPS = 60
screenWidth = round(224 * scalefactor)
screenHeight = round(298 * scalefactor)
size = screenWidth, screenHeight
screen = display.set_mode(size)
button = 0
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
titleFont = font.SysFont("Times New Roman",45)

def drawText(words,screen,position,color,font):
    text = font.render(words, False, color)
    textSize = text.get_size()
    position[0] = position[0] - textSize[0]//2
    position[1] = position[1] - textSize[1]//2
    #centers the text
    screen.blit(text,position)

def gameRun():
    drawGameScene()
    eventCheck()
    updater()

def eventCheck():
    for events in event.get():
        if events.type == QUIT:
            quit()
            exit()

def updater():
    pass

def drawGameScene():
    draw.rect(screen,RED,(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight))
    drawText("High Score", screen, [0,0], BLUE, titleFont)
    #display.update()

while True:
    gameRun()
    display.flip()
```